# Formatting a grid in python

Tags: python, datagrid

As title says, I want to output a grid with its axis labeled on the left and bottom in python. Here is the current method:

```
    def printG(self):
    for Row in range(self.rows):
        for Column in range(self.cols):
            print(self.Grid[Row][Column], end=' ')
        print('|{0:>3}'.format(Row))
    for Column in range(self.cols):
        print(Column, end=' ')
    print ()
```

The issue is that as soon as it reaches double digits it doesn't match with the grid anymore:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  0
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  1
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  2
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  3
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  4
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  5
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ |  6
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  7
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  8
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |  9
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 10
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 11
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 12
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 13
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 14
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

The list it uses is shown below (stored in a class with above method):

```
[['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']
 ['_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_' '_']]
```

Is there a way to format this so that it stays in line with the grid? (hopefully without an external module)

Comment: The code you put isn't properly formatted and errors and even after fixing indentation it prints nothing?

Comment: @Riceblades What formatting error are you referring to?

Comment: The code you put just literally isn't functioning code